# Flip animation only renders half during animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a div that once you hover over it flips to reveal content on the other side. It is working pretty good but I ran into one issue which I can't figure out.

When the flip animation is happening only half of the content that is gonna be revealed during the flip is showing, I can't seem to figure out where this is coming from and it's bothering me alot.

```js
$(function() {
  var frontHeight = $('.front .inner').height();
  var backHeight = $('.back .inner').height();
  var noImg = false;

  if ($('.front-image')) {
    noImg = true;
    $('.flipper').height(backHeight);
  }

  if (frontHeight > backHeight && !noImg) {
    $('.flipper').height(frontHeight);
  } else {
    $('.flipper').height(backHeight);
  }
})
```

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front,
.flip-container:hover .front-image {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.front .inner h3,
.back .inner h3 {
  color: white;
}

.front-image,
.front-image .inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* flip speed goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back,
.front-image {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */

.front,
.front-image {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/*
 Some vertical flip updates
*/

.vertical.flip-container {
  position: relative;
}

.vertical .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.vertical.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>
          cool
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempor tincidunt massa, et commodo lorem tincidunt auctor. Duis eu nisi bibendum, vehicula elit in, congue ex. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec ac leo eu ante vulputate efficitur. Vivamus
          lobortis blandit elit, sit amet iaculis neque cursus nec. Etiam convallis erat ac eros blandit, in pharetra urna tristique. Suspendisse sapien dolor, tincidunt id ante vel, venenatis molestie lectus. Ut mattis interdum sapien, ac ornare erat
          maximus et. Fusce vestibulum ultricies eros vel rutrum. Integer et libero sit amet diam tincidunt dapibus eu vitae nunc. Sed ultricies leo quis leo semper, nec maximus leo interdum. Morbi porta tortor eget velit sodales, quis venenatis ante
          blandit.
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not working because of background color on .flipper element.
Just remove the "background-color" property from .flipper and assign it to both .back and .front elements.

```
.front, .back, .front-image {
    ...
    background-color: #3498db;
}
```

Here's working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ymuovwnb/1/

Comment: Thanks alot! I was breaking my head over this haha

Comment: You can also add a `body { background-color: black } ` to keep a color in the background while it's flipping, or just put it inside a `div` with a colored background.

Answer (score 0):

Change your flipper div like this:

```
<div class="flipper" style="height: 300px;">
```

Comment: Still the same issue, and the height of the div is set via the javascript

Comment: @Jan-WillemdeBoer, I checked with your jsfiddle. It worked well when I changed the height. JS is not working with fiddle. It says $ is not defined.

Comment: Okay but thats not the issue, the issue is when you hover over the div that during the hover only half the content is showing and once the hover is finished you see all content

Comment: @Jan-WillemdeBoer have a look at the answer by me, thats all you need

Comment: @Jan-WillemdeBoer, what do you mean by hover is finished? Hover is considered finished as soon as you stop your pointer movement. So when I go over the blue area, it flips and I can see the whole text on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, try removing the background color from the `div` which is getting flipped

```js
$(function() {
  var frontHeight = $('.front .inner').height();
  var backHeight = $('.back .inner').height();
  var noImg = false;

  if ($('.front-image')) {
    noImg = true;
    $('.flipper').height(backHeight);
  }

  if (frontHeight > backHeight && !noImg) {
    $('.flipper').height(frontHeight);
  } else {
    $('.flipper').height(backHeight);
  }
})
```

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
body{
    background-color: #3498db;
    }
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front,
.flip-container:hover .front-image {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.front .inner h3,
.back .inner h3 {
  color: white;
}

.front-image,
.front-image .inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* flip speed goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back,
.front-image {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */

.front,
.front-image {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/*
 Some vertical flip updates
*/

.vertical.flip-container {
  position: relative;
}

.vertical .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.vertical.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>
          cool
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempor tincidunt massa, et commodo lorem tincidunt auctor. Duis eu nisi bibendum, vehicula elit in, congue ex. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec ac leo eu ante vulputate efficitur. Vivamus
          lobortis blandit elit, sit amet iaculis neque cursus nec. Etiam convallis erat ac eros blandit, in pharetra urna tristique. Suspendisse sapien dolor, tincidunt id ante vel, venenatis molestie lectus. Ut mattis interdum sapien, ac ornare erat
          maximus et. Fusce vestibulum ultricies eros vel rutrum. Integer et libero sit amet diam tincidunt dapibus eu vitae nunc. Sed ultricies leo quis leo semper, nec maximus leo interdum. Morbi porta tortor eget velit sodales, quis venenatis ante
          blandit.
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```